# Replace multiple occurrences with single select statement in sql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

1st is sentence table having title column with values

```
my name is A  
B is my name   
i am A boy
```

2nd is dict table having val column and val1 column with values

```
val         val1   
A           B   
B           A  
boy         girl
```

I want to write a query which replace every occurrence of val in title column with val1 without using cursor.

Comment: the result should be

Comment: my name is B  A is my name and i am B girl

Comment: What SQL type are you using?  i.e. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...

Comment: You need change your first table to be more specific about the placeholder. Something like `my name is {A}` otherwise you can replace something like `boycott` to `girlcott`

Answer (score 0):

In MySql you can use replace  and like

```
select s.title,  replace (s.title, d.val, d.val1) as replaced
from  sentence as s
join dicts as d on (d.val like  concat(s.val , ' %') 
                          or d.val like  concat('% ',s.val , ' %') 
                          or d.val like  concat('% ',s.val ) );
```